# Aho-Corasick algorithm

Tags: c++, string, aho-corasick

Please help me to find mistakes in this code.I wrote a simple program that adds n strings to trie by Aho-Corasick algorithm,but it doesn't work correctly.It crashes after entering strings.What's wrong with this code?

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#define ALPHABET 26

using namespace std;

struct item
{
       int next[ALPHABET];
       int leaf;
       item()
       {
               for (int i = 0; i < ALPHABET; i++)
                       next[i] = -1;
               leaf = 0;
       }
};

vector <item> trie;

int add_string(string &s)
{
       int z = 0;
       item temp;
       for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
       {
              char c = s[i] - 'a';
              if (trie[z].next[c] == -1)
              {
                     trie[z].next[c] = trie.size();
                     trie.push_back(temp);}
                     z = trie[z].next[c];
              }
              trie[z].leaf = true;
       }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
       int n;
       cin >> n;
       string s[n];
       for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
              cin >> s[i];
       for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
              add_string(s[i]);
       system("PAUSE");
       return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: have you even tried to debug anything ?

Comment: How does it crash? What's the error message?

Comment: Note: `string s[n];` makes use of a gcc-ism. In C++ arrays dimensions should be fixed at compile-time (unless dynamically allocated), VLA (Variable-Length Arrays) are strictly C99 and using them in C++ is non-standard (and thus non-portable). The recommendation is to use `std::vector<std::string> s(n);` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about the algorithm, so I have no idea if it is running correctly. However, just based on running your code through gdb, you need to start out with at least one element in your `trie` vector. You could do that by writing

```
vector <item> trie(1);
```

where the `1` signifies how many elements the vector should start out with. With that change, the code runs fine (but I don't know if it is running the algorithm correctly).

Comment: I think you are right.I will add search function to check if it works.